# Relative Strength Index calculation using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I am trying to calculate relative strength index (RSI) using pandas and can't seem to properly adapt a solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526414/relative-strength-index-in-python-pandas/23495349#23495349).  Why isn't this returning a RSI series?

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 8)
end = datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 8)
stock = 'TNA'
price = web.DataReader(stock,'yahoo', start, end)

n = 14

def RSI(series):    
    delta = series.diff()
    u = delta * 0 
    d = u.copy()
    i_pos = delta > 0
    i_neg = delta < 0
    u[i_pos] = delta[i_pos]
    d[i_neg] = delta[i_neg]
    rs = moments.ewma(u, span=27) / moments.ewma(d, span=27)
    return 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)

print(rsi(price, n))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shot in the dark because you did not provide very much context.

`pandas.stats.moment.ewma` is no longer supported in 0.23.0.  Exponentially weighed windows are now achieved using `pd.Series.ewm`.  This returns [exponentially-weighted-windows object](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/computation.html#exponentially-weighted-windows) window object that cannot be used in any sort of equation without providing a method for the rolling window.  Here is a list of the available methods:

```
rs.agg         rs.apply       rs.count       rs.exclusions  rs.max         rs.median      rs.name        rs.skew        r.sum
rs.aggregate   rs.corr        rs.cov         rs.kurt        rs.mean        rs.min         rs.quantile    rs.std         rs.var
```

I assume you copied the function above from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23495349/2864250), which did not even seem to answer the OP.  If you wanted to do this analysis with the series `price.Close` with span `n` and compute the `mean` of each exponentially weighted window:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import pandas as pd

ewma = pd.Series.ewm
start = datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 8)
end = datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 8)
stock = 'TNA'
price = web.DataReader(stock,'yahoo', start, end)

n = 14

def RSI(series,n):    
    delta = series.diff()
    u = delta * 0 
    d = u.copy()
    i_pos = delta > 0
    i_neg = delta < 0
    u[i_pos] = delta[i_pos]
    d[i_neg] = delta[i_neg]
    rs = ewma(u, span=n).mean() / ewma(d, span=n).mean()
    return 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)

print(RSI(price.Close,n))
```